# How to initialize an object of IScope and ISCEService classes?

Tags: angular, object, scope, initialization

I have a module which class' constructor has two arguments: the first one is $scope, and the second, $sce. The type of the first one is IScope and the type of the second, ISCEService.

So my class and its constructor is:

```
class ComparisonComponent {
   ...
   constructor(public $scope: ng.IScope, public $sce: ng.ISCEService) {
       ...
   }
   ...
}
```

My question is: How can I declare an object of type ComparisonComponent?

```
var comp = new ComparisonComponent(what goes here?);
```

Comment: You shouldn't. The thing you've called a 'component' is basically controller class. It's supposed to be instantiated by the framework. Where did you get this idea? Please, provide detailed information on your case, including http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Excuse me, @estus, I am trying to use this ts module: https://github.com/bill-long/angular-rich-text-diff/blob/master/angular-rich-text-diff.ts but I can't.

Comment: Where are you trying to use it? It is AngularJS module that is supposed to be used in AngularJS app.

Comment: I was wondering if I can use it in an Angular 5 app...

Comment: No. AngularJS and Angular are different frameworks. And there are fundamental differences in the parts that are affected by this extension, it needs to be rewritten from the ground up. If you're really after this functionality and cannot find it anywhere else, you can add nested AngularJS app to Angular 5 app just for this component. There will be certain inconveniences with this approach that should be properly addressed, I wouldn't recommend that if you're not comfortable enough with both frameworks.